# Relationship between electron $g$ value and fine structure constant from QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants, magnetic-moment

The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) on the fine structure constant says that 'The theory of QED predicts a relationship between the dimensionless magnetic moment of the electron and the fine-structure constant $\alpha$' but doesn't give the mathematical expression of this relationship. What is this relationship, how is it derived -- roughly speaking -- from QED and where can I find it written down?

Comment: Peskin & Schroeder chapter 6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia - Gyromagnetic ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#For_an_isolated_electron) the $g$-factor of the electron
in terms of the fine structure constant $\alpha$ is
$$g_e=2\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}+ \cdots \right).$$
(The $\cdots$ here stand for higher powers of $\alpha$.)

This formula can be derived from quantum electrodynamics.
Considering more and more complex Feynman diagrams in the calculation
yields the terms proportional to $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^3$, ....

[image: Feynman diagrams]
<sub>(figures from "[Theory of the Anomalous Magnetic Moment of the Electron](https://www.mdpi.com/2218-2004/7/1/28/htm)" which in turn took the figures from
"[Quantum electrodynamics calculation of lepton anomalous
magnetic moments: Numerical approach to the perturbation
theory of QED](https://academic.oup.com/ptep/article/2012/1/01A107/1569493)")</sub>